# $f_{n}(x)=(x+\frac{1}{n})^2$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$, converges pointwise to $f(x)=x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I am trying to prove that $\{f_{n}(x)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, where $f_{n}(x)=(x+\frac{1}{n})^2$, and $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Converges pointwise to $f(x)=x^2$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Is the following correct?

Consider arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Consider arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ I now argue that there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ $\implies$ $|(x+\frac{1}{n})^2-x^2|<\epsilon$.

First, suppose that $x\geq 0$. Then $(x+\frac{1}{n})^2$ is monotone decreasing for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and bounded below by $x^2$. Thus, there must exist an $n^*$ big enough such that $n>n^*$ $\implies$ $(x+\frac{1}{n})^2<x^2+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Set $N=n^*$. Then, $n>N \implies$ $|(x+\frac{1}{n})^2-x^2|<x^2+\frac{\epsilon}{2}-x^2<\epsilon$

Second, suppose that $x<0$. Then $(x+\frac{1}{n})^2$ is monotone increasing for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and bounded above by $x^2$. Thus, there must exist an $n^*$ big enough such that $n>n^*$ $\implies$ $(x+\frac{1}{n})^2>x^2-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Set $N=n^*$. Then, $n>N \implies$ $|(x+\frac{1}{n})^2-x^2|=x^2-(x+\frac{1}{n})^2<x^2-x^2+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$

Comment: This works. If you're allowed to leverage the continuity of $x\mapsto x^2$, you can get an alternative solution by noting that $x+1/n\to x$ pointwise and consequently $(x+1/n)^2\to x^2$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Might be easier to note that $|(x+{1 \over n})^2-x^2 |\le {2 \over n} |x| + {1 \over n^2}$, and then choose $n$ according to your $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

For each fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the expression $f_{n}(x)$ behaves in the same way as a sequence depending on $n$.

Having said that, you can apply the arithmetic properties of sequences to obtain the desired result:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x) & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x^{2} + \frac{2x}{n} + \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\\\\
& = x^{2} + 0 + 0 = x^{2}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!